# Get peoples surnames or christian names from freebase?

Tags: freebase

Is it possible to get a users first name or surname from a freebase query?
For example, I have a person entry I have the id of, but I just want to extract their first name.

{
  "id": "/en/paul_thomas_anderson",
  "name" : null
}​

How would I modify this query, its something I've found nothing about by googling or searching here on S.O.?   I know this kind of thing is possible in dbpedia for most people entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible directly.  The name is stored as a single unit.  There are topics for given names and surnames (e.g. http://www.freebase.com/view/base/givennames/given_name), so you could split the name and see which list(s) it appears in, but that's indirect and doesn't tell you about the specific person you are querying.

Comment: ah ok a shame, in this respect it seems an advantage to dbpedia (im comparing the two for a possible project). Do you know if you can you add substr to queries though in freebase as a way of doing queries that retrieve only surnames?